# How to avoid dummy variable trap for multiple category in one column

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data, dummy-variable, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a regression problem. I have a categorical column which has 24 categorical value.One-hot encoding is showing too many dummy variable. Is there a way to avoid multiple dummy variable trap. Kindly  guide me 
here is my sample of the categorical column
[image]

After label encoding

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Too vague.  Please prove a [mcve]

Comment: thank you for  your reply i have uploaded the original columns and encoded columns in post

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d','a','c','a','d'], columns=['column'])
```

Output:

```
   column
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       0
5       2
6       0
7       3
```